# How does one await the result of a deferred operation with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

```
function z(){
setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("A")
    },3000)
}

z()
console.log("B")
```

output i expected

```
A(3 sec delay)

B
```

output i got

```
B

A(3 sec delay)
```

how to get synchronous behavior with this asynchronous code?

Comment: This is how `setTimeout` works, see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). The callback function inside is *a function to be executed after the timer expires*.

Comment: Depending on the context there are basically two options: (1) Make `z` accept a callback that gets called after the timeout expired. Put `console.log('B')` there. (2) Convert `z` into returning a promise (which resolves when the timeout expired) and use `await z()`. This way you can  still  *write* the code in a synchronous way.

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: What's the point in your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a first solution the OP needs to ...

- write a `wait` function which accepts a number value (representing milliseconds) and returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance which [resolves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#description) after the provided delay.
- utilize the `wait` function by logging the to be delayed value after the awaited time via the promise' [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method.

```js
function wait(msec) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, msec)
  );  
}

console.log('A');
wait(3000)
  .then(() => console.log('B'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

For a second solution the above provided code could be rewritten into an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which does log both of the OP's values and does, in between the logging, [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the promise returned by `wait`.

```js
function wait(msec) {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, msec)
  );  
}

(async () => {

  console.log('A');
  await wait(3000);
  console.log('B');

})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

after learning promise , i am able to come up to a solution

```
'''let z=()=>{
return new Promise( (resolve,reject )=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve (console.log("A"))
                     },3000)
    
                                    }
)
    
}

async function lol(){
 await z()
console.log("B")
}
lol()'''
```